# Automatic placement of caret after open curly brace in Idea

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea, preferences, indentation, haxe

In the IntelliJ Idea when I editing AS3 class I see good behavior of auto-placement of caret after open curly brace - Idea will add new tab to new line:

Before:

[image: Flash/AS3: state one]

After:

[image: Flash/AS3: state two]
 - Idea add tab for me! Thats great!

---

But when I work in Haxe classes I observe the following behavior:

Before:

[image: HaXe: state one]

After:

[image: HaXe: state two]
 - no additional tab

What did I do wrong and **How to make so that in the second case was like the first behavior?**

Comment: Sidebar question: Have you used [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) before?

Comment: No. At this Mac and OS. How FD can may affect to the Idea's work?

Comment: you did nothing wrong - it's a bug. Please vote for [HAXE-354](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/HAXE-354)